# Ranking Data Based on Matches

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that identifies 'potential' duplicates based on multiple columns (V1,V2,V3,V4) in my database, but it is returning many matches making it difficult for a manual review, so I would like  to assign some ranks to the data based on:
a. if V5,V6 match - rank -1
b. if V7,V8 match - rank -2
and so on.

Along with the above, V1,V2,V3,V4 will match based on my current query. Is this possible with dense_rank()?

**My current query is along the lines of:**

```
SELECT ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate
FROM   (
  SELECT T1.ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate,
         COUNT(*)
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct,
         COUNT( CASE CreatedDate WHEN DATE '2017-08-01' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_date_match
  FROM   T1
         INNER JOIN T2
         ON ( T1.ID = T2.ID )
         INNER JOIN T3
         ON ( T1.ID = T3.ID )
)
WHERE  ct > 1
AND    ct_date_match > 0
```

**T1**

```
ID |   V1 |  V2 |  V5   | V6 | CreatedDate   
---| ---  | ---    ---   --- ----------  
1  |   A  |  US |  1984 | QR | 01-AUG-2017  
2  |   B  |  FR |  1991 | TY | 01-JAN-2017  
3  |   C  |  AU |  1989 | GH | 25-SEP-2017  
4  |   B  |  FR |  1995 | BN | 01-AUG-2017  
5  |   A  |  US |  1984 | QR | 30-MAR-2016  
6  |   C  |  AU |  1999 | MK | 14-JUN-2015
```

**T2**

```
ID | V3    | V7    
---| ---    ---                
1  | Apple   D12    
1  | Kiwi    S45    
2  | Pear    T23           
3  | Banana  U78           
4  | Pear    T23    
5  | Apple   D12    
6  | Banana  P90
```

**T3**

```
ID | V4      V8    
---|  ---    ---    
1  | Spinach A678    
1  | Beets   V902    
2  | Celery  T456    
3  | Radish  Y675    
4  | Celery  T456    
5  | Spinach G890     
6  | Celery  F567    
6  | Radish  R453
```

**Current Output:**

```
1 A US Apple Spinach  
5 A US Apple Spinach  
2 B FR Pear  Celery  
4 B FR Pear  Celery
```

**Expected Output:**                     Rnk

```
1 A US Apple Spinach 1984 QR D12 A678 1    
5 A US Apple Spinach 1984 QR D12 G890 1    
2 B FR Pear  Celery  1991 TY T23 T456 2     
4 B FR Pear  Celery  1995 BN T23 T456 2
```

Comment: Why is US/Kiwi/Beets included in the output? There only seems to be a single match for that combination? Running your query with the sample data doesn't include it.

Comment: sorry, yes I have updated the output.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I follow, but it looks like you can add partition counts of distinct V5/6/7/8 values to your inner query, and then evaluate those in the outer query:

```
SELECT ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate,
  CASE WHEN ct_v5 = 1 AND ct_v6 = 1 THEN 1
       WHEN ct_v7 = 1 AND ct_v8 = 1 THEN 2
  END AS rnk
FROM   (
  SELECT T1.ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate,
         COUNT(*)
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct,
         COUNT( CASE CreatedDate WHEN DATE '2017-08-01' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_date_match,
         COUNT( DISTINCT V5 )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_v5,
         COUNT( DISTINCT V6 )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_v6,
         COUNT( DISTINCT V7 )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_v7,
         COUNT( DISTINCT V8 )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_v8
  FROM   T1
         INNER JOIN T2
         ON ( T1.ID = T2.ID )
         INNER JOIN T3
         ON ( T1.ID = T3.ID )
)
WHERE  ct > 1
AND    ct_date_match > 0;
```

Which with your data gets:

```
        ID V V2 V3     V4      CREATEDDAT        RNK
---------- - -- ------ ------- ---------- ----------
         1 A US Apple  Spinach 2017-08-01          1
         5 A US Apple  Spinach 2016-03-30          1
         2 B FR Pear   Celery  2017-01-01          2
         4 B FR Pear   Celery  2017-08-01          2
```

This doesn't have a row for US/Kiwi/Beets, but the sample data only seems to have one set of those, and your original query doesn't report it either.